# Add scores to contact form 7 email results

Tags: jquery, contact-form-7

I've created a website which uses jQuery to ask and score a series of questions.

```
$("#next01").click(function() {
    if ($("#question01").is(":checked")) { 
        $("p.score01").html("correct");
    } else {
        $("p.score01").html("incorrect");
    }
});
```

This obviously changes the content of a paragraph tag to display whether the answer is a correct or incorrect.

There is a Contact Form 7 form on the page too.

Is it possible to feed this information into my Contact Form 7 email results so that the receiver gets the scores email to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - there was no actual content in the input - it was defined by the value tag...so i used the attr method to change the value.

```
$(".span-name input").attr("value","correct");
```

Thanks all the same - appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this is to create a hidden score field on your contact form. Give it an id, and use it in your Contact Form 7 email just like any other field. Then just use your jQuery to update the value of that field with the correct score.

Comment: Of course! - don't know why i didn't think of that - many thanks

Comment: I tried this and I'm struggling - it will pass the answer to a paragraph on the form but it won't pass the answer to the form if it's in a [text] tag - its weird - i've tried targeting the input too

Comment: Can you post the relevant snippets of the contact form 7 template and the javascript you're using to update it?

Comment: In Contact form 7...
This works: <p class="score01">null</p>
This doesn't: <p>[text q-score01 class:score01 "null"]</p>